# Select item from spinner to show edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-spinner

I am trying to show an EditText when a certain Item from a Spinner is selected. So far I have created the spinner and the EditText but I don't really know what my next step is.
I don't want to display the selection in the EditText, I just want to display the EditText field.

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text_box);
    editText.getText().toString();




}


public void addItemsOnSpinner()
{
    spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource
    (this, R.array.spinner_item, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner1.setAdapter (adapter);

}

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> spinner1, View view,int pos, long id)
{

        editText.setText(spinner1.getSelectedItem());

}
```

This is also what I have in my string array + wish to only display the edittext box when item2 is selected

```
<string-array name="spinner_item">
    <item>Item 1</item>
    <item value="Item2">Item 2</item>
    <item>Item 3</item>
    <item>Item 4</item>
</string-array>
```

Comment: change object name of EditText to editText or edit1 or etName , `EditText` is not allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set visibility of `editText` to invisible or gone in XML, depends on what suits your needs better. Then you can use following to make it appear:

```java
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> spinner1, View view, int pos, long id)
{
    yourEditText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            int x = spinner1.getSelectedItemPosition();
            valSel = items[x];
    }
String spinner1val = spin1.getText().toString();         //extract value of text from spinner

EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText1);  //get id of EditText box
text.setText(spinner1val);
```

Alternatively, if you want to check the value of item selected in Spinner, the 'valsel' contains the value. Just Toast the valsel.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set text on edittext `onItemSelected` . First do change as per **MKJParekh** Suggest.

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> spinner1, View view,int pos, long id)
{
   yourEditText.setText(spinner1.getSelectedItem())
}
```

Comment: I have followed what MKJParekh has said and also tried what you have suggested but it is now telling me editText cannot be resolved

Answer (score 0):

Get the selected values from the spinner,

```
String anyvariable=String.valueOf(spin.getSelectedItem());
```

Now you can show this String value in the edit text,

```
EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.your_text);
text.setText(anyvariable);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> month, View arg1,int arg2, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            selectedMonth=  month.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString();
            Log.d("Tag",""+selectedMonth);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //selected_item=    arg0.getChildAt(1).toString();

        }
        });

        selected_item contains the item ,so just set it to editView like
         editView.setText(selected_item)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. EditText height1, weight1, height, weight; Spinner height_spinner,
   weight_spinner; String heightInputString, weightInputString; Button
   calculatebmi;

   @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_bmi);

   ```
   // set your class members as they start out null.
   // do this for all of them 
   height1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.idofheight1inxml);
   height_spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.idofheightspinnerinxml); 
   ....

       // Show the Up button in the action bar.
   setupActionBar();
   setupSpinners(); }
   ```

   void setupSpinners(){
       height_spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
           @Override
           public void onItemSelected(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
           //I.E. if in the height spinner CM is selected I would like to hide the second height edittext field. 
           // I'm not sure if this is meant to be "height1" or "height"
               if (position == 0){
                   height.setVisibility(View.GONE);
               } else {
                   height.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
               }
           }

   ```
       @Override
       public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

       }
   });

   // if you want to add similar logic for weight spinner, do that with this : 
   weight_spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
       @Override
       public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
           // put your code here for weight spinner
       }

       @Override
       public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

       }
   }); }
   ```