# Change the value of edittext depend on spinner value

Tags: android, spinner, android-edittext

I have problem with my homework,
how to change the value of edittext based on spinner value,
so if the spinner value is "A" then the edittext will filled by "1"

I am new to android application, so I don't understand how to change it.

> [image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12317093/1168654

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use like following.

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

       public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (spinner.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("A")) {
                  editText.setText("1");    
        } else if (spinner.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("B")) {
                  editText.setText("2");    
        }
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
});
```

I hope this will help you.